# Changing the Display URL Using Mod Rewrite

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to change the display URL from

```
 www.site.com/blog/events/
```

to

```
 www.site.com/events/
```

I have installed WordPress in

**/blog/** directory and have installed a plug-in for **/events/** for dynamic event management.

Basically, I want to get rid of **/blog** in the URL when **/events/** occurs in the URL.

I have tried various rewrite rules using .htaccess file but none of the rules worked out.

Also, there are 2 .htaccess files (the first .htaccess file is the default file found in the root path of the web server and the other is the default WordPress .htaccess file presents inside **/blog/** directory).

I am little confused on which .htaccess file I need to try the URL mod rewrite rule.

How to do this using URL mod rewrite conditional rule?

Please help me to see the light. Any support would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in htaccess root directory :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^events/(.*)$ /blog/events/$1
```

The first line allows you to rewrite url. The second line check if the url begin with "events/",  and if it's the case, the server is going to look files in the real "blog/events/" directorie.

Comment: Yes no problem. i will do it.

Comment: I updated my answer. If I could help you, you can validate my answer.